# AChartEngine Graph with long legends

Tags: achartengine

I have a LineChart with 4 lines and their legends are long so I can only see the first two... I tried to put a ScrollView but it didn't work. What can I do? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Shorten the series titles so that you get shorter stuff in the legend.
- Increase the legend height `renderer.setLegendHeight();`
- Make the legend auto-resizable `renderer.setFitLegend(true);`